# Управление пакетами шрифтов.

Tags: html, css, шрифты

Я скачал шрифт, а там целый пак шрифтов - `Regular, Bold, Light, Italic...`
Если я подключу обычный шрифт (`Regular`), то я не смогу использовать жирный за счет `font-weight: bold`. Нужно подключать жирный и ставить его в `font-family`. Мне это неудобно.
Можно ли как-нибудь объединить все шрифты в 1?
Или подключить нужные мне (`bold, regular`) и управлять ими через соотвествующие CSS свойства, а не через один лишь `font-family`?

Comment: У меня тоже были проблемы с шрифтами с гугл и я хотел бы узнать ответ. Но если вам действительно нужен ответ покажите код как вы подключаете все дело и дайте больше подробностей.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@font-face {
font-family: roboto;
src: url('../fonts/roboto/roboto-bold.eot');
src: url('../fonts/roboto/roboto-bold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('../fonts/roboto/roboto-bold.woff2') format('woff2'),
     url('../fonts/roboto/roboto-bold.woff') format('woff'),
     url('../fonts/roboto/roboto-bold.svg#robotobold') format('svg');
font-weight: bold;
font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
font-family: roboto;
src: url('../fonts/roboto/roboto-regular.eot');
src: url('../fonts/roboto/roboto-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-
opentype'),
     url('../fonts/roboto/roboto-regular.woff2') format('woff2'),
     url('../fonts/roboto/roboto-regular.woff') format('woff'),
     url('../fonts/roboto/roboto-regular.svg#robotoregular') format('svg');
font-weight: 400;
font-style: normal;
}
```

Для каждого начертания свое правило @font-face с одинаковым названием шрифта. Это позволяет менять font-weight  без изменения font-family.

Answer (score 1):

Обратите внимание на свойство [font-style](http://htmlbook.ru/css/font-style) для придания шрифту наклона:

> Когда для текста установлено курсивное или наклонное начертание,
>   браузер обращается к системе для поиска подходящего шрифта. Если
>   заданный шрифт не найден, браузер использует специальный алгоритм для
>   имитации нужного вида текста.

А также на свойство [font-weight](http://htmlbook.ru/css/font-weight) для задания толщины:

> Устанавливает насыщенность шрифта. Значение устанавливается от 100 до
>   900 с шагом 100.